# Не выводятся данные range слайдера из jquery-ui

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, jquery-ui

Делаю range-slider при помощи jquery-ui и столкнулся с проблемой вывода данных.

```js
$(function(){
 var d = $("#left > .left-count");
 var r = $("#right > .right-count");

 $(".js_subscribed").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 1000,
  max: 8000000,
  step: 1000,
  values: [50000, 7000000],
  create: function(event, ui) {
   d.text($(this).slider("value") + "k");
   r.text($(this).slider("value") + "m");
  },
  slide: function(event, ui){
   d.text(ui.value + "k");
   r.text(ui.value + "m");
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div>
  <div id="sub">Values:</div>
  <div class="js_subscribed">
      <div id="left" class="ui-slider-handle">
        <span class="left-count"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="right" class="ui-slider-handle">
        <span class="right-count"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Сделал по аналогии с примерами, но получилось вот что. Подскажите что необходимо изменить чтобы данные слева принадлежали только левому ползунку а данные справа правому соответственно.

Comment: Вы уже вставляете код в вопрос. Желательно довести его до ума, чтобы люди, которые захотят Вам помочь, могли его запустить. Опытный же пользователь.

Comment: @Igor Я хотел это сделать, но не разобрался в настройке, не сказал бы что я такой уж опытный))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что установка свойства `value` через вызов метода jQuery `$("#sub").val()` для элемента `div` не имеет смысла. Поменяйте на `$("#sub").html(...)`. А лучше:

```
<div id="sub">Values: <span></span></div>
```

и

```
$("#sub > span").html(...);
```

> как можно вывести данные под ползунки

Выводите их прямо **на** ползунки:

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle

*Update*

```
slide: function(event, ui){
  $(ui.handle).text(ui.value + $(ui.handle).data("suffix"));
}

<div id="left" class="ui-slider-handle" data-suffix="k">
  <span class="left-count"></span>
</div>
<div id="right" class="ui-slider-handle" data-suffix="m">
  <span class="right-count"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ очень помог благодарю, но не могли бы вы еще раз помочь? Вопрос и код в примере поправил, можете посмотреть в чем дело.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev , вместо "два раза ui.value" используйте `ui.value[0]` и `ui.value[1]` . Пример https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range (жмакать view source)